# Find column form value

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A is the point (98, -17) and B is the point (-39, 39).  The vector $\vec {BA}$  has column form given by
$\left( \begin {array}{c} h \\ k \end {array}\right)$

What is the value of h?

Cant figure how to resolve this..
do i need to add point A and B after converting them to component form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have them in components.  The vector is from $B$ to $A$, so you need to subtract the components, which is subtracting $\vec {OA}- \vec {OB}$.

Comment: is it 137? i minus B-A

Comment: OK i am totally confused now i flipped thru my textbook and couldnot find anything, a bit more further explanation will be great. I am totally confused is what are O values? in OA?

Comment: $O$ is the origin.  If you plot $A$ and $B$ on graph paper, you can draw an arrow from B to A.  The $x$ coordinate is the horizontal part of this vector and the $y$ coordinate is the vertical part of it.

Comment: A nasty person made up the problem. Note that to find $XY$ we calculate $OY-OX$. So to calculate $BA$ we calculate $OA-OB$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so my answer is correct? +137?

Comment: @JackyBoi: Yes, it is correct, $98-(-39)$.

Comment: @JackyBoi:  I confused myself, and André Nicolas got it right.  I have fixed the answer.